# Reflect the line $y=x$ in the circle $|z-2|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, symmetry

I have the following problem:

Reflect the line $y=x$ in the circle $|z-2|=1$.

I know that the map $$z\mapsto\frac{R^2}{\overline{z}-\overline{a}}+a$$ take a point to a symmetric point respect to the circle $|z-a|=R$.

So, in this case $\infty\mapsto2$ and $(1+i)\mapsto\frac{3+i}{2}$.

Both points are in the line $x+y=2$. To find the reflection I think that I have to consider the system of equations given by

$$2=\frac{r^2}{2-\overline{a}}+a,$$ $$\frac{3+i}{2}=\frac{r^2}{\frac{3-i}{2}-\overline{a}}+a.$$

I know that the answer is $$\left|z-\frac{7+i}{4}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4},$$ but from the previous equations I can't get there. What I'm missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should the answer be $\left|z-\frac{7+i}{4}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$?

Comment: How about just setting $z=t(1+i)$ and simplifying? You should know even without having seen the solution that the image is a circle.

Comment: @amd I knew that the image was a circle. With a good draw is simple to answer, but I don't know why the method is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, if $z$ is a point on the image, then the reflectional image of $z$ is on the line.

$y=x$ can be written as $z=i\bar z$. The image of $z$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\bar z-2}+2$. So we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\bar z-2}+2&=i\left(\frac{1}{ z-2}+2\right)\\
\frac{2\bar z-3}{\bar z-2}&=\frac{i(2z-3)}{z-2}\\
2z\bar z-3z-4\bar z+6&=i(2z\bar z-4z-3\bar z+6)\\
z\bar z-\frac{3-4i}{2(1-i)}z-\frac{4-3i}{2(1-i)}\bar z+3&=0\\
z\bar z-\frac{7-i}{4}z-\frac{7+i}{4}\bar z+3&=0\\
\left(z-\frac{7+i}{4}\right)\left(\bar z-\frac{7-i}{4}\right)&=\frac{1}{8}\\
\left|z-\frac{7+i}{4}\right|&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you ! The method that I use only works when the symmetric points lies in the real axis. I think that there is a rotation, maybe, what I'm missing. Because in this case, the symmetric points lies in $x+y=2$.

Comment: Can I use the same method if the line is given by $y=3x$? How would I do it in this case?